# Adding source archives to local file based library in gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

In my current project, I need to use the [tween-engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine) library, the download includes the api and source jars. I can add the tween-engine-api.jar (api) file to my projects dependencies with

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: '*-sources.jar')
}
```

but then I can't add the tween-engine-api-sources.jar (sources) file as the source for the actual library. Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to tag the files so gradle picks up the -sources.jar file the way I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue, ended up merging the library jar and the sources jar into one, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Adding sources and Javadoc Jars for local libraries will be supported in Gradle 1.12 or 1.13. Note that if you add sources to the main Jar, Java compilers that find this Jar on their compile class path will usually try to compile the sources (!).