# Add sources and Javadoc Jars to Gradle for local flatdir dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle project with Koltin-DSL which stores the dependencies in a local directory called `lib`. This folder contains my `commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar` dependency.
How can I reference an additional `commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar` which contains the sources for this dependency?
After a Gradle import, my IDE (IntelliJ) should be able to find the source code for this dependency, in my local filesystem - without searching it only.

##### Project Structure

```
root
 - app
   - lib
     commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
     commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar <-- I want to reference this
  build.gradle.kts
```

##### `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs("lib")
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation(":commons-lang3:3.12.0")
}
```

On Maven this would work, by just follow the naming pattern with the suffix `sources.jar`.
I found an answer, from [Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448170/4198170) that:

> Adding sources and Javadoc Jars for local libraries will be supported in Gradle 1.12 or 1.13
> But I didn't find any hint in the Gradle Doku, how to setup.

The `commons-lang3` was just an example, and I know I can just add it as regular dependency and let the IDE download the sources from maven central. But I have other dependencies which are not published in the maven central or GitHub. So how could I just point Gradle to the Source file or JavaDoc - without manual choosing the files in the IDE with *Choose sources...:
[image]*

Comment: Instead of using flatDir you can try to create a local Maven repository and put these libraries there. See the related discussion https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-supply-source-jars-from-flatdir-for-eclipse-debugging/35670/7